# WebStorm use Regex to add quotations around found matches

Tags: regex, webstorm

Given the following array:

```
R991,U847,L239,U883,L224,D359,L907,D944,L79,U265,L107
```

I'd like to add quotation around each individual instance of a letter followed by a number of characters using the 'search and replace' function.

Now in the search function I can target all the instances using the Regex option, and using `[A-Z]\d*`.

Now for the replace value, how can I use a certain wildcard character to keep the same Regex value intact?

Example:

[image]

The end result should be:

```
"R991","U847","L239","U883","L224","D359","L907","D944","L79","U265","L107"
```

*Note: As a quick fix I searched for each `,` and replaced that with `","` which almost fixed it entirely. But I'm wondering for more complex cases you could use a wildcard.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for: `([A-Z]\d+)`
Replace by: `"$1"`

[image]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html#capture_groups_and_backreference